# lambda expression in LINQ to XML

Tags: xml, lambda, linq-to-xml

Please check my code -
XML-

```
 <LocalXML>
  <PnrDetails SearchType="Outbound">
    <GDSPNR></GDSPNR>
  </PnrDetails>
  <PnrDetails SearchType="Inbound">
    <GDSPNR></GDSPNR>
  </PnrDetails>
</LocalXML>
```

Code -

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"RSP.xml");
            var ele = doc.Root.Elements("PnrDetails");
            foreach (XElement e in ele)
            {
                if (e.Element("GDSPNR").Value.Equals(""))
                {
                    e.Elements().Remove();
                    e.Add(new XElement("ErrorMessage", "Booking is not confirmed")
                    );
                }
            }
```

My code is working fine.Now my question is that can I use Lambda Expression in above code to check whether GDSPNR value null or not.If yes then please tell me how?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT XML -

```
<LocalXML>
  <PnrDetails SearchType="Outbound">
    <GDSPNR></GDSPNR>
    <SPNR>abc</SPNR>
    <DSPNR>xyz</DSPNR>
  </PnrDetails>
  <PnrDetails SearchType="Inbound">
    <GDSPNR></GDSPNR>
    <SPNR>abx</SPNR>
    <DSPNR>cds</DSPNR>
  </PnrDetails>
</LocalXML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (based entirely on what your current logic is doing):

```
    IEnumerable<XElement> nodesToBeReplaced = document.Root
        .Elements("PnrDetails")
        .Descendants("GDSPNR")
        .Where(element => element.Value.Equals(string.Empty));

    foreach (XElement element in nodesToBeReplaced)
    {
        element.Name = "ErrorMessage";
        element.Value = "Booking is not confirmed";
    }
```

If instead you mean, PnrDetails without a child tag of GDSPNR, like this:

```
  <PnrDetails SearchType=""Outbound"">
  </PnrDetails>
```

Then you can do the following:

```
    IEnumerable<XElement> nodesWithMissingChildElements = document.Root
        .Elements("PnrDetails")
        .Where(element => !element.Descendants("GDSPNR").Any());
```

Comment: In my other condition I have more then one nodes in PnrDetails element.If I used your code, it is only replace GDSPNR node.If I want to remove all the nodes in PnrDeatils attribute and add only ErrorMessage node, what will I do?

Comment: You could then go back up to the parent and remove all of the Siblings:  nodesToBeReplaced.Select(x => x.Parent).Descendants().Where(x => x.Name != "GDSPNR").Remove();. You could also use NextNode and PreviousNode to find the siblings or break the query up into two parts- find the ones who children are in error, remove the siblings and then add/replace the GDSPNR Element

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"RSP.xml");
    var ele = doc.Root.Elements("PnrDetails");
    foreach (XElement e in ele.Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)e.Element("GDSPNR"))))
    {
      e.Elements().Remove();
      e.Add(new XElement("ErrorMessage", "Booking is not confirmed"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well what would you consider a "null" check for an XML element node? Your current code checks whether the Value property is an empty string, if all you want to do is move the check of the `if` statement up into your query expression then do e.g.

```
  var ele = doc.Root.Elements("PnrDetails").Where(p => p.Element("GDSPNR").Value == "");
```

Or do you want to check whether there is a child element `GDSPNR` at all:

```
  var ele = doc.Root.Elements("PnrDetails").Where(p => p.Element("GDSPNR") != null);
```